# OpenLdap redirect on write

Tags: redirect, ldap, openldap

I am currently trying to setup a redirect on write for an installation of OpenLdap 2.2.

I have two instances running. One is configured to be read-only (only read access, database specified as read-only) and has redirect configured to point to the second instance. The second instance is configured to allow for the desired write permissions.

When I attempt a modify on the first instance it fails as expected but does not send back the referral. Am I missing a piece of the configuration? Am I even on the right path? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the best way to do this is to go ahead and set up replication using slurpd and point all requests at the slave instance. Unfortunately you can't set up the master and slave on the same host (for obvious reasons, but still), so I had to spin up a second VM to get this going.

Honestly, if I was not trying to replicate a redirect problem it wouldn't be worth it, but I have to duplicate a production issue.

For more information on slapd and specifically slurpd, the OpenLDAP documentation is actually crazy helpful: [slurpd config for OpenLDAP 2.2](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/replication.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the database section of you `slapd.conf` do you add the redirection like this ? :

```
updateref  "ldap://master-host:port/"
```

Comment: I was using 'referral "ldap://alternate-domain.com:port/"'. Updateref was what I ended up with, but within the context of a slurpd master-slave configuration. It cannot be used alone.